# Windows service runs file locally but not on server

Tags: windows-services, service

I created a simple Windows service in dot net which runs a file. When I run the service locally I see the file running in the task manager just fine. However, when I run the service on the server it won't run the file. I've checked the path to the file which is fine. Below is the code used to launch the process which runs the file. Any ideas?

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // TODO: Add code here to start your service.
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("VirtualCameraService started");

    // Create An instance of the Process class responsible for starting the newly process.

    System.Diagnostics.Process process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

    // Set the directory where the file resides
    process1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\VirtualCameraServiceSetup\\";

    // Set the filename name of the file to be opened
    process1.StartInfo.FileName = "VirtualCameraServiceProject.avc";

    // Start the process
    process1.Start();
}
```

Comment: what version of windows?  is UAC enabled?

Comment: It's Windows Server Enterprise 2007. UAC is disabled for almost everything except:"Only elevate UIAccess applications that are installed in secure locations". "Behavior of elevating prompt for standard users" is set to "Prompt for credentials" And "Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode" is set to "Elevate without prompting"

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct is to check permissions.

Comment: Yea that was one of the first things I was thinking too. I checked all the permissions, and they are all correct.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file extension registered on the server?  It could be that the server is failing to find an action associated with `.avc`.  You might want to move this to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) since it is most likely a configuration or Windows OS version difference.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to put a try catch block in that method and write out any exception to the event log, this should piont you in the write direction.

But as D.Shawley said it sounds like a config issue.

Comment: Yea I think this is a config issue. I put a try catch block in the method, and unfortunately there are no exceptions being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, once again the problem was that the file wasn't associated to the program on the server. So instead of trying to open the file I needed to open the program to run the file, then pass the file as an argument to the program. Below is the syntax.

```
// Set the directory where the file resides
process1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Axis Communications\\AXIS Virtual Camera 3\\";

// Set the filename name of the file to be opened
//process1.StartInfo.FileName = "VirtualCamera.exe C:\\VirtualCameraServiceSetup\\VirtualCameraServiceProject.avc";
process1.StartInfo.FileName = "VirtualCamera.exe";
process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "VirtualCameraServiceProject.avc";
```